# Using Django template together with React

Tags: reactjs, django

Is it possible to use Django template together with React? If so, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two separate projects:
(I would think about it as backend and frontend)

1. Backend = Django/Flask/FastAPI or any other framework
2. Frontend = React application

If you have these two services you can start thinking about communication between them (the easiest by REST). So you should provide some API available for you're frontend to ie fetch the data.